# Why does host key verification fail? Symfony and BitBucket Deployment with Easy-Deploy-Bundle

Tags: php, git, symfony, ssh, bitbucket

I am trying to deploy my Symfony 5 application via BitBucket Pipelines and easy-corp/easy-deploy-bundle to my server. I've followed the instructions on https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-ssh-keys-in-bitbucket-pipelines/ to create an ssh key and added my server as a known host within BitBucket. I also followed the instructions at https://github.com/EasyCorp/easy-deploy-bundle/.

The error I get within the pipeline when running `php bin/console deploy -v` is:

```
[...] Executing command: echo 1234353400
| err :: Host key verification failed.
In Process.php line 252:
                                                                               
  [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException]                 
  The command "ssh ... -p ... 'echo 1234353400'" failed.  
                                                                               
  Exit Code: 255(Unknown error)                                                
                                                                               
  Working directory: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build                      
                                                                               
  Output:                                                                      
  ================                                                             
                                                                               
                                                                               
  Error Output:                                                                
  ================                                                             
  Host key verification failed.
```

I've added the public key from Symfony to the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`on my server.

My config file for deployment (`deploy.php`) looks as follows:

```
<?php

use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyDeployBundle\Deployer\DefaultDeployer;

return new class extends DefaultDeployer
{
    public function configure()
    {
        return $this->getConfigBuilder()
            ->server('user@host:port')
            ->deployDir('dir')
            ->repositoryUrl('ssh-url')
            ->repositoryBranch('develop')
        ;
    }
};
```

Where user, host, port, dir, and ssh-url are replaced by my credentials, which work fine when accessing the server via ssh in the terminal.

So what am I doing wrong? Is easy-deploy-bundle accessing the valid .ssh directory, where BitBucket stores my key and known host?

I found that `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` could be a possible solution, but I didn't found how to disable it within easy-deploy-bundle.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found that `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` could be a possible solution, but I didn't found how to disable it within easy-deploy-bundle.

That means you have actually *not* [added the remote server fingerprint to the `known_hosts`](https://serverfault.com/a/971922/783).

- either you have added the hostname only, and it needs the IP (or vice-versa)
- or you have added it using one account (`~/.ssh/known_hosts`), but the plugin is executed by another account (or `root`), and does not read the right `known_hosts`